# Can't added back my client for microsoft networks in Windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares, network-adapter, ipv4

I can't open network shared folders. Got to looking at my NIC properties, and I found that I was missing everything buy IPv4 and IPv6. So I started to try to add back to client, and protocol. I can't seem to add them back every time I do I receive an error: "Could not add the requested feature. The error is no such interface supported"

- Windows 10 64 Bit Build 10122
- I know they were installed and working

Here are some pics:

[image]

[image]

Can someone tell me how to fix this or how I can get around it so I can access my network shares? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would reinstall Windows 10 to see if you can recreate the environment in order to report the bug that resulted in this feature being removed.

Comment: @Ramhound Re-installation is not really an option.

Comment: Have you tried to add the feature manually using DISM?  Stuff not working is what you should expect from pre-released versions of Windows, this might be a known issue, have you reported the issue to Microsoft?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I have reported to Microsoft. How would I use DISM to fix my issue?

Answer (score 0):

My machine updated to the new build (10130) of Windows 10. After the update my NIC setting were restored.